# Python: RuntimeError: Iterator CreateCompatibleStrides may only be called if DONT_NEGATE_STRIDES was used to prevent reverse iteration of an axis

Tags: python, numpy

Hey for some reason I can run my application in LiClipse, but the exact same code cannot be run from the command line. When executing the following method a runtime error occurs.

```
def truncateOperator(self, v, k):
    """ Performs the truncate operation for a vector in the TPower
    algorithm.
    Inputs:
        v:      The vector to truncate
        k:      The number of elements of the vector to keep
    Outputs:
        u:      The v vector zeroed apart from the k highest elements.
    """
    u = zeros(v.shape[0])
    sortedIndices = argsort(abs(v), axis=0)
    sortedIndices = fliplr(sortedIndices.T).T

    vRestricted = v[sortedIndices[0:k],0]
    normV = 0
    if isinstance(vRestricted, csc_matrix):
        normV = norm(vRestricted.todense())
    else:
        ## Code fails here! ##
        normV = norm(vRestricted)
    if normV == 0:
        return csc_matrix(zeros(v.shape[0]))
    a = array(double(vRestricted))/normV
    u[sortedIndices[0:k]] = a[0:k, 0]
    u = csc_matrix(u)
    return u
```

The error is:
RuntimeError: Iterator CreateCompatibleStrides may only be called if DONT_NEGATE_STRIDES was used to prevent reverse iteration of an axis

If anyone could help me fix this then that would be great. I want to be able to run it from the terminal.

Thanks, 
Theo

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally forgot the actual question. How do I fix this?

Comment: There should be an edit option near the bottom of your question.

Comment: Can you check that you're using the same numpy from the commandline as from LiClipse? E.g., `import numpy; numpy.__file__` should be the same in both cases.

Comment: Perfect! They seem to be different. How do I make the terminal one use the same one as the LiClipse one?

Comment: You should try and use the python executable that LiClipse uses. You may be able to deduce the executable from the numpy path you just got, but that will depend on your OS/platform.

Comment: My problem is that I want this to be open source, not just an executable and I want to ensure that the person who runs it next to be able to run it also. How can I ensure that?

Comment: Well, it looks like your two Python executables are compiled differently. I've never come across this error before (and I can't test unless you can provide a minimal working example), so likely the one you use on the command line is the odd one out. Where did you get that one/how did you install it?

Comment: The two files are:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/__init__.pyc
for LiClipse

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.9.0.dev_297f54b-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/numpy/__init__.pyc
for terminal

I honestly don't remember how I installed them :S

Answer (score 0):

You've installed the `numpy` version provided by the [scipy superpack](https://github.com/fonnesbeck/ScipySuperpack), which appears to have been compiled with (or rather, without) this `DONT_NEGATE_STRIDES`.

I'd suggest two possible things:

- report this error as an issue into the issue tracker on the scipy superpack [issue page](https://github.com/fonnesbeck/ScipySuperpack/issues?page=1&state=open). They may help you resolve this.
- alternatively, remove this package (and possibly other scipy superpack packages installed). You can just remove the complete `*.egg` directory from the `site-packages` directory. 
  Then, install numpy again using `pip`: `sudo pip install numpy`. Do the same for other required packages that you previously obtained from the scipy superpack (e.g. scipy, pandas etc). This may take a while, since it will be compiled on your system (i.e., you're not downloading binaries). This requires XCode and its command line tools to be installed (gcc/clang mostly).

My own preferred alternative is using [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) instead, to install the most recent Python version (thus not using the system python), and use the corresponding `pip` to install all necessary packages (this avoids putting stuff in `/System` and `/Library`, like it does now.).

Finally, there is a work-around as well without removing or installing new things, though I don't directly recommend it, because it will bite you in some way in the future: use `PYTHONPATH`:
Set your PYTHONPATH to point to the LiClipse packages on the command line:

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
```

This will put the LiClipse packages path first in line to be found, before the scipy superpack packages.

Comment: Thank you so much for this thorough explanation! I will try it out. I have just mentioned the issue on the issue tracker for the scipy superpack. I'll probably wait till after my presentation though to actually mess with the libraries as I know it now runs at least on Eclipse and I will need to demonstrate that at least. Then I will fix everything up. 

Thank you so much again :)